# Why this weird value is assigned?

Tags: ruby

```
class MyClass
  def fun
    a = 2
    b = 5
    yield(a,b)
  end

  def self.fun2
    puts self
  end
end

m = 1
n = 2
mine = MyClass.new
mine.fun {|m| puts "m = #{m} n = #{n}"}
```

Here I deliberately do not match the number of parameters for yield, and the output is

```
test.rb:16: warning: multiple values for a block parameter (2 for 1)
from test.rb:5
m = 25 n = 2
```

Where does this 25 come from?

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: sorry it's actually 1.8.7... I have 1.9.2 on my linux and I'm currently on my mac...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you to be in `1.8.x`.

In which case, `m` will be `[a, b]`. Which is equivalent to `[2, 5]`.

```
[2, 5].to_s
# => "25"

"m = #{[2, 5]} n = #{2}"
# => "m = 25 n = 2"
```

Comment: Nice guess on the version number.

Answer (score 0):

The 25 comes from `a` and `b` passed to `m` as an array.

When you `puts` it, that's the output you get in Ruby 1.8.

You could also try doing `puts "m = #{m.inspect}...."` or `puts "m = #{m.class.to_s}"`